# Multiple checkboxes, comma separated get request?

Tags: checkbox, get

I have this form with get set as method.

```
<form method="get" action="index.html">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit, i end up with the url 
index.html?item=1&item=2

I wonder if it is possible to make a more neat format like comma-seperation, for instance
index.html?item=1,2

I have been searching for a while, but I cannot find how to obtain this. Do I really need to implement this with javascript?

Comment: Thats true. We can not create that action URL in form level. We have to use javasript to create the action url. SO call all checkbox and their value, create an url then, submit the from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    

    function submitForm(){
    var name=document.getElementsByName('item[]');
    var str="";
    for(i=0;i<(name.length);i++){
      if(name[i].checked){
         str+=name[i].value+",";
      }
    }
    if(str.length>0){str=str.substring(0,str.length-1)};// remove the last comma
    var url="actionpage.html?item="+str;
    document.getElementById('formid').action=url;
    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
    }
```

Please rename the checkbox to item[], this will create an array. Then call this function in your button click event.